# divs problems with position in header and main

Tags: css, html, header, position

i have a page with 3 parent divs , now im having problems positioning the divs inside the header div.
my code is something like this:

divs layout:

```
<div id="layout">
    <div id="header" class="body">
        header
        <div id="logo">logo</div>
        <div id="menu">menu</div>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="left">left</div>
        <div id="right">right</div>
        <div id="body">body</div>
        <div id="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

css is something like this:

```
.body {
 background-color: #ffffff;
 margin: 0px;
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 background-image: url(imgs/back.png);
}

#layout {
 margin:auto;
 width: 1024px;
 background-color:  #ffffff;
}

#main {
   background-color:  #ffffff; 
}

#header {
 background-color:#0F0;
 height: 300px;
}

#body {
 margin-left: 180px;
 margin-right: 180px;
 padding: 5px;
 background-color:  #ffffff;
}

#footer {
 margin-left: 180px;
 margin-right: 180px;
 padding: 0px;
 background-color:  #ffffff;
}

#right {
 float: right;
 width: 180px;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 right: 0px;
    background-color:  #ffffff;
}

#left {
 float: left;
 width: 180px;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 background-color:  #ffffff;
}

#clear {
   clear:both; 
}
```

i want to put in a position of header div (e.g.  vertical: center , horizontal: 0 px (0 pixels of the header div not of the total page) on left side) and menu in other position (e.g. vertial: top , horizontal: between the center and right side (center and right side of header div only again).

i would appreciate a solution.

thanks to all.

Comment: A live example usually helps with questions like these, but fear not for I have the power: http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/wxkBX/ !

Comment: Also, a screenshot of what your desired outcome is very helpful, I have no idea what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I could be more helpful if you could clarify your question.

I am not sure of what your are asking for in terms of the location for the header.

Here is an approach to move the menu between the center and the right column. Nest the menu and the right hand column in another right aligned div. For the purposes of example I have called it `right-container`.

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="layout">
    <div id="header" class="body">
        header
        <div id="logo">logo</div>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="left">left</div>
        <div id="right-container">
           <div id="menu">menu</div>
           <div id="right">right</div>
        </div>
        <div id="body">body</div>
        <div id="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">footer</div>
</div>​
```

And here are the css statements I added:

```
#right-container {
 float: right;
 width: 360px;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 right: 0px;
    background-color:  #ffffff;
}

#menu {
 float: left;
 width: 180px;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 background-color:  #ffffff;
}
```

You can see the fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/SkLvX/